# Vue not updating v-for info array

Tags: vue.js, data-binding, v-for

I am using v-model="item1" in a form which calls a method AddItem().

```
<form @submit.prevent="AddItem">
         <input type="text" name="items" v-model="item1">
...
```

The method AddItem sends the input data to the database and also pushes to an array called info[].

This array is defined in data(){...}.

```
  data () {
    return {
    info: [],
    item1: null
    }
  },
```

The method,

```
  AddItem(){
      db.collection('things').add({
        item1: this.item1,
      }).then(() => {
        this.info.push(this.item1)
      }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        })
   }
```

But the info is also used in a v-for in next in the template just after this form. I thought if the info array was updated that any use of it in the template would also update. But after I successfully send this data to the db and update info, the new item is not visible in v-for iteration in the template.

```
  <li v-for="(item, index) in info" :key="index">
           <span class="item">{{ item.item1 }}</span>
        </li>
```

How can I get this for loop to take account of the updated info array?

I am new to vue but guess that maybe I should be using data binding some way.

---

## Solved

I was pushing the value to the info array instead of pushing an object like this,

```
this.info.push({item1: this.item1})
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem in a fiddle? Try [jsFiddle's Vue Boilerplate](https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/vue).

Comment: Did you console.log if the info array was getting pushed correctly

Comment: @Helpinghand Just figured it out, that is what was wrong. I was pushing the value instead of an object. This is what is needed, this.info.push({item1: this.item1}) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in info" :key="index">
  <span class="item">{{ item }}</span>
</li>
```

The value that you push into the array is a string instead of an object (this.item1).
Also to make it more simple try to only do this in AddItem(). Then you are sure its not a faulth with your backend.

```
AddItem(){
  this.info.push(this.item1)
}
```

Otherwise your code looks correct. In the future it is always handy to create a fiddle so its easier for others to help you.

Comment: Yes and what worked for me in the end was this.info.push({item1: this.item1}) Thanks for looking at it